# Merge all elements from Map<String, Object> to one Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, java-stream

There is a MapA, it may contains MapB, and the MapB may contains MapC ..., the following is the MapA structure,

```
Map<String, Object> mapA = new HashMap<>();
```

the data in Map will be like

```
[
K1=V1,
K2=V2,
K3=V3,
node1={K11=V11, K12=V12, node11={K111=V111, K112=V112, K113=V113}, K13=V13, K14=V14},
K4=V4
]
```

now I'd like these to merge all these key-values into one Map, just like

```
[
K1=V1,
K2=V2,
K3=V3,
K11=V11, 
K12=V12, 
K111=V111, 
K112=V112, 
K113=V113,
K13=V13, 
K14=V14,
K4=V4
]
```

I have write a function like below

```
    private Map<String, Object> getMap (Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> mmm = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            mmm.putAll(getMap((Map<String, Object>) value));
            return mmm;
        }
         mmm.put(key, value);
    }
    return mmm;
}
```

Comment: "the result is not correct". In what way exactly?

Comment: what's the output you got ?

Comment: @tgdavies the result I got is missing some fields, for example, K4 is missing, K13, K14 missing as well

Comment: I have figure out what is going on.  cannot `return mmm` in the `if` statement, if return, it will missing the fields behind map.

Comment: @GBMan Why did you put `java-stream` tag? Do you need to implement this using Stream API?

Answer (score 1):

correct one:

```
    private Map<String, Object> getMap (Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> mmm = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            mmm.putAll(getMap((Map<String, Object>) value));
        } else {
            mmm.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    return mmm;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The input map contents may be flattened into a one-level map using `Stream::flatMap`, however, the `flatten` method should be invoked recursively and marked with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation to avoid warning about potentially unsafe casting:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
public static Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> (e.getValue() instanceof Map) ?
            flatten((Map<String, Object>) e.getValue()).entrySet().stream() :
            Stream.of(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue
        ));
}
```

Test:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = Map.of(
    "K1", "V1",
    "K2", "V2",
    "K3", "V3",
    "node1", Map.of(
        "K11", "V11", 
        "K12", "V12", 
        "node11", Map.of(
            "K111", "V111", 
            "K112", "V112", 
            "K113", "V113"
        ), 
        "K13", "V13", 
        "K14", "V14"
    ),
    "K4", "V4"
);
System.out.println(flatten(map));
```

Output (unsorted):

```
{K111=V111, K112=V112, K1=V1, K2=V2, K3=V3, K4=V4, K11=V11, K113=V113, K13=V13, K12=V12, K14=V14}
```

---

If the insertion order needs to be maintained and the input map and nested maps provide ordering (that is, it is a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap`), `LinkedHashMap` should be supplied to the collector and returned by `flatten` method:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> (e.getValue() instanceof Map) 
            ? flatten((Map<String, Object>) e.getValue()).entrySet().stream() 
            : Stream.of(e)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            (v1, v2) -> v1,
            LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
}
```

Output (ordered by some insertion):

```
{K1=V1, K2=V2, K3=V3, K4=V4, K11=V11, K12=V12, K13=V13, K14=V14, K111=V111, K112=V112, K113=V113}
```

Comment: Yes whatever you did is correct.